# Demux realisation in hardware

Tags: digital-logic, system-verilog

Following the previous post
[Output of XOR gate with high-impedance input](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/198940/output-of-xor-gate-with-high-impedance-input)

I am interested further how four-valued logic of SystemVerilog gets eventually implemented in hardware.

**Could someone correct / confirm my next observations**?

Consider

```
assign LED = (select) ? value1 : value2;
```

- Observation 1:

  ```
    select ? value1 : value2
  ```

  in four-valued logic *is not* equivalent to

  ```
    (select & value1) | (!select & value2)
  ```

  When

  ```
  select = u; value1 = 1; value2 = 1;
  ```

  *during simulation and in hardware* value of LED will be one, whereas

  ```
  (u & 1) | (!u & 1) = u | !u = u | u = u;
  ```

  (*note, in SystemVerilog undefined value u is represented as x*)

  **What is the semantics of (a ? b : c) expression? What about semantics of** *case* **and** *if* **statements?**
- Observation 2:

  X value after synthesis is initialised to 0 by default.
  For example:

  ```
  select = x; value1 = 0; value2 = 1;
  ```

  turns the LED on, whereas

  ```
  select = x; value1 = 1; value2 = 0;
  ```

  keeps the LED off.

  **If in hardware x is 0 by default, why is extra value required during simulation, wouldn't having 0, 1 and z be enough?**
- Observation 3:

  The hardware behaviour when

  ```
  select = z
  ```

  is super-weird. In this case LED is on if and only if

  ```
  value1 = 1; value2 = 1;
  ```

  **What is happening in this case (c.f. observation 2)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The X value only exists in simulation or as an input to synthesis - it does not exist in hardware.

In a pure algebraic system, each unknown value would be given a unique variable name, like \$x\$, \$y\$ and \$z\$ or \$X_{1}\$, \$X_{2}\$, and \$X_{3}\$. A symbolic or formal evaluation would be \$x|!x \equiv 1 \$. However, Verilog simulation uses a single \$x\$ value that represents *all* unknowns. So the \$value(x)|!value(x) = value(x)\$. In fact, any binary operation will return an *x* value.

Verilog's conditional operator \$select?value_{1}:value_{2}\$ is less pessimistic in simulation.  When \$select \equiv x\$, it evaluates \$value_{1} \equiv value_{2}\$ and returns either value when they are the same.

The branching statements in Verilog like **if** are overly optimistic in simulation. An expression that evaluates to an X value is considered false, and takes the false branch.

Comment: "When select≡x, it evaluates value1≡value2 and returns either value when they are the same", what does it return when they are not the same?

Comment: It returns the value when not the same.

Comment: Which value (i.e. value1 or value2)?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say it returns the value X when select=x and the two values are not the same. This is all described in section _11.4.11 Conditional operator_ of the 1800-2012 SystemVerilog Standard